# silverlight app using both windows and forms authentication

Tags: silverlight-4.0, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have a Silverlight RIA application that uses Forms authentication. We want to pass users of a certain domain through Windows authentication and if that fails or user is not part of that domain it falls back to Forms authentication.

Most of the stuff I've found was for aspx sites using methods not available in Silverlight. Many others say it isn't possible. Has anybody managed to do this without to much trouble?

The app is based on the Silverlight Business Application template in VS2010 (SL4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Ran into the same issue and decided to turn off windows authentication.

See:

- http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/228703.aspx
- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/566410/enable-wcf-ria-services-with-forms-authentication-and-integrated-windows-authentication

The second link seems to indicate this is a bug that may be resolved in a future release

Comment: OK, but are you familiar with Active Directory? Is that the same as windows authentication or is it usable alongside forms authentication?